# Finding the number of elements in the first index of the array given (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm currently working on a HC single linkage method in Python and when I'm cluster each element I'm storing the current clusters as:

```
array1=[(0, 1), (3, 5), 2, 4]
elements1=len(array1[0])
array2[((3, 5), 4), (0, 1), 2]
elements2=len(array2[0])
```

What I want to do is find the number of elements in the zero'th index of each array, for the first elements1 I get the correct answer of 2 but for elements2 I also get 2 but it should be 3, I can see the problem however I can't seem to be able to work around

Comment: Can you clarify the expected input and output?

Comment: If each array in array_1 and array_2 respectivley, I'm trying to find number of elements at array_1[0]=(0.1)=2 elements and array_2[0]=((3,5)4)=3 elements

Comment: I don't follow, can you clarify what your inputs are and what output you're looking for for those inputs, and edit those into your original question?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I've updated it with minor code and another explanation, hopefully it makes more sense thanks!

Comment: The first element of `array2` has two members.  That's just a fact.  If you want a RECURSIVE count, you will have to write a function to do that.

Comment: What you need to do is flatten those inner lists.  And extensive discussion of the options is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: Okay thanks i'll have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In array2, the first index has a tuple of size 2, the first element is another tuple `(3, 5)`, and the second element is a single int `4`

If you want `len(array2[0])` to return 3, you have to unpack all the values present at that index.

That can be done by the following code:

```
length = len(array2[0])
if isinstance(array2[0][0], tuple):
    length -= 1 
    length += len(array2[0][0])
    # replacing one with the size of the tuple
```

You can do this in a loop to check for all instances.

I tried to find a method to unpack the values you have, but that did not work, this was the next best solution.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Happy to help you out!